# Dynamically enumerate object from vertical to horizontal

Tags: powershell

I have got data with PowerShell into a object as below, now i would like to convert it from vertical to horizontal. (Like "Text to column" function in Excel). How can I dynamically enumerate "all row 1" as an object header and the rest of them will assign to its child items?

The input file contains three columns, "Row", "Column" and "Text", in PSObject

```
PS > $table

Row Column Text
--- ------ ----
  1      1 Dept
  1      2 Time
  1      3 Day1
  1      4 Day2
  1      5 Day3
  1      6 Day4
  1      7 Day5
  1      8 Day6
  1      9 Day7
  2      1 Marketing
  2      2 11:00
  2      3 4
  2      4 8
  2      5 8
  2      6 8
  2      7 4
  2      8 0
  2      9 0
  3      1 Finance
  3      2 09:00
  3      3 4
  3      4 8
  3      5 8
  3      6 8
  3      7 4
  3      8 0
  3      9 0
```

I tried to use the following code to assign it into another object, but I don't know how to let the content put in.

```
$data = New-Object –TypeName PSObject

$table | %{
    if ($_.row -eq 1) {
        $data | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name $_.text –Value ''
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
PS > $data|ft

Dept Time Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day5 Day6 Day7
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
```

Expected result:

```
Dept      Time  Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day5 Day6 Day7 
----      ----  ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
Marketing 11:00 4    8    8    8    4    0    0
Finance   09:00 4    8    8    8    4    0    0
```

Comment: Sury.C - do you actually have a CSV with 3 columns named Row/Column/Text? or do you have a file with one column - the one you named Text?

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what *specific* problem (in your code) do you need help with?

Comment: Sorry, i add some information again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a need for some kind of *indirect reference*. You can do the following:

```
$dataLabels = New-Object –TypeName psobject
$dataZero   = New-Object –TypeName psobject
$data       = @()        ### or ### New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$table | Where-Object { $_.row -eq 1 } | ForEach-Object {
    $dataLabels | 
      Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name $_.Column –Value $_.Text
    $dataZero | 
      Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name $_.Text   –Value ''
  }
$dataZeroCsv = $dataZero | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
for ( $i=0;$i -lt ($Table.Row|Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum -1;$i++)
{
    $dataLine = $dataZeroCsv | ConvertFrom-Csv
    $table | Where-Object { ($_.Row - 2) -eq $i } | 
        ForEach-Object {
           $dataLine.($dataLabels.($_.Column)) = $_.Text ### indirect reference
        }
    $data += $dataLine   ### or ### [void]$data.Add( $dataLine )
}

## Output:
$data | Format-Table
```

provided that `$table` is defined as follows:

```
$tableArr = @"
Row Column Text
  1      1 Dept
  1      2 Time
  1      3 Day1
  1      4 Day2
  1      5 Day3
  1      6 Day4
  1      7 Day5
  1      8 Day6
  1      9 Day7
  2      1 Marketing
  2      2 11:00
  2      3 4
  2      4 8
  2      5 8
  2      6 8
  2      7 4
  2      8 0
  2      9 0
  3      1 Finance
  3      2 09:00
  3      3 3
  3      4 4
  3      5 5
  3      6 6
  3      7 7
  3      8 0
  3      9 1
  4      1 TestDept
  4      2 16:00
  4      4 5
"@  -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
$table = $tableArr -replace '\s+', ' ' -replace '^\s', '' | 
            ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' '
```

**Output**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\52804963.ps1

Dept      Time  Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day5 Day6 Day7
----      ----  ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
Marketing 11:00 4    8    8    8    4    0    0
Finance   09:00 3    4    5    6    7    0    1
TestDept  16:00      5
```